# Change TextareaAutosize color in React with mui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textarea

I'm new at React and using mui components.

While I'm trying to set color to TextareaAutosize mui component with code like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextareaAutosize from '@mui/material/TextareaAutosize';
import { blue } from '@mui/material/colors';

export default function EmptyTextarea() {
  return (
    <TextareaAutosize
      aria-label="empty textarea"
      placeholder="Empty"
      style={{ width: 200, color: blue, background: blue}}
      //Also not works: color="{blue}"
    />
  );
}
```

the color of the component not changed.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

`<TextareaAutosize />` renders a plain [HTMLTextAreaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement).

Which means this CSS will work:

```css
textarea {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #BADA55;
}
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/maxheighttextarea-material-demo-forked-5hc8nv?file=/index.css

If you want to scope the CSS to your particular instance, give it an `id` and use it in the CSS selector.